# ASP.NET Core 2.0 site POST request resulting in 404 on Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I've just upgraded an ASP.NET Core 1.1 web application to 2.0 and tested without issue locally. However, when the site is deployed to Azure a POST request that worked locally results in a 404 (I guess this could be the same for all POST requests, but I'm unable to log-in due to the issue).

Any ideas why this might fail to be working when deployed to Azure but working perfectly when run through IIS Express locally?

I deleted the original deployment slot on Azure and re-created as initially deploying over the slot mixed old 1.1 DLL's with the newer 2.0 DLL's and prevented the site working at all.

Comment: Have tried activating logging? Maybe you can get some clues there?

Comment: @AlexAlbu thanks, that's where I found the real issue. Just need to work out why I was receiving a 4040 instead of an error response code!

Answer (score 3):

Seems I was caught out by poor handling of errors by my web application. I'd assumed that `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error")` (I default my HomeController to not require the leading "Home" for  /Home/Error) in `Startup.cs` would redirect to an error page, but for me it is not.

My underlying issue was a database connection error that caused the POST controller method to fail. I was caught out by the response returning a 404 rather than an error status.

I will need to investigate how error handling works in more detail for ASP.NET Core it seems.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was about to ask a question and this q was suggested. As soon as I added some logging I quickly discovered SQLite was the actual issue!

Comment: But if this was a server error, wouldn't it have happened also in your local IIS?

Comment: @Jamo I have different databases locally vs Azure so use different database connection strings.